# Only options for 'trans' are 'noop', 'context "xxx"', and 'as VAR'

Tags: django, django-templates

in my template than contains {% i18n %} i receive this error :

```
Only options for 'trans' are 'noop', 'context "xxx"', and 'as VAR'.
```

for this line of my template:

```
title="{% trans site_title = settings.APP_SHORT_NAME %}RSS feed from {{ site_title }}{% endtrans %}"
```

Comment: `{% trans site_title = settings.APP_SHORT_NAME %}` should be `{% trans site_title as settings.APP_SHORT_NAME %}`and there is no tag called `endtrans` - Just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it should be:

```
title="{% blocktrans with site_title = settings.APP_SHORT_NAME %}RSS feed from {{ site_title }}{% endblocktrans %}"
```